# python import error because sys.path refer to another directory

Tags: python, sys.path

I have two folder with version1 and version2 with the same structure and nearly the same code (I'm using the version2 for experimenting with some refactoring) but if I print `sys.path` all the import in Version2 still refer to Version1, therefore if I change one of the modules in V2/utils and I try to import it in V2/readfile.py I get an import error.

```
├── /myProject  
│   ├── V1  
│   │   ├──utils  
│   │   ├──readfile.py
│   ├── V2
│   │   ├──utils 
│   │   ├──readfile.py
```

The problem is temporarily solved if I remove from `sys.path` the V1 and append the V2, but I wish to know how did I mess up with python path and why this is happening, and how I can solve this problem permanently without remove/add path on `sys.path` for each module.

I'm developing in an Anaconda virtual environment and my OS is Windows10.